# Static function pointer java

Tags: java

Say I have 2 methods that look like this:

```
private static boolean validate1(String line)

private static boolean validate2(String line)
```

The method I use depends what the user passes in as an argument so I only ever want to use one of the methods.

If I wanted to loop through a list of strings would I have to check each time what method to use or is there a way I could store the method I wanted and just call it with the parameters like a function pointer?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use Java 8 or higher, you can do the following.

Create a functional interface for your methods like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Validator {
    boolean validate(String s);
}
```

In you class with your 2 static methods, you can now assign one of these methods to a variable. Depending on the argument, you can assign the validate1 method:

```
Validator v = this::validate1;
```

or the validate2 method:

```
Validator v = this::validate2;
```

Then you can use your Validator object  in your loop to perform your validation.

```
for(String s : strings) {
    v.validate(s);
}
```

Or with the new forEach() method in the List interface, or with the Streams API. You can use it how you like.

Comment: How do they avoid iterating the strings?

Answer (score 2):

Because the signature of your validate methods are the same, you can map a [`Function<String, Boolean>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) to a string like so:

```
class Main {
    public static boolean validate1(String s) { return true; }
    public static boolean validate2(String s) { return false; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Function<String, Boolean>> funcMap = new HashMap<>();
        funcMap.put("First", Main::validate1);
        funcMap.put("Second", Main::validate2);
        System.out.println(funcMap.get("First").apply("Wow!"));
    }
}
```

The output here would be `true`.

Comment: Any ideas why this was downvoted? This seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: @gil.fernandes, can't say when they don't leave comments. Good news is one account - one vote. If you think it's a good one you're welcome to upvote it :)

Comment: Really: I think your answer is valid: you store function pointers (method reference) in the map which you then use to execute a static method.  +1